# Can I make siunitx commands use serif fonts like the rest of the math in beamer?

Tags: fonts, beamer, math-mode, siunitx

In a beamer presentation I can use `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` to typeset the math in a serif font while the rest of the presentation is in a sans-serif font. But the `\SI` command from `siunitx` appears to typeset its argument as text, which means it follows the text font style, not the math one. Is there a way I can change this so that quantities with units appear with a serif font just like other math, whereas the text is still sans-serif?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  Text appears in sans-serif font

  $x,2y,3z$ appears in serif font

  $\SI{1}{m}$ appears in sans-serif font, would like it to be serif
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I've tried things like `\sisetup{math-rm=\mathrm, text-rm=\rmfamily}` or passing the `detect-family` option to `siunitx`, but no luck.

Of course I could just change the font family of the entire document to be serif, but I'd like to know whether I have another option.

Comment: Where are you doing the `\sisetup`? `siunitx` deliberately tests for 'all sanserif' using the `\AtBeginDocument` hook, so to reverse that you need to either do `\sisetup` after `\begin{document}` or use `\AtBeginDocument` from the preamble.

Comment: Ah, that's the issue, I had `\sisetup` before `\begin{document}`. I could accept that if you'd like to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`siunitx` checks if the document font is sanserif using the `\AtBeginDocument` hook, and adjusts the default if it is. That reflects the fact that in most cases if people set their document all sanserif the desired outcome is that `siunitx` also uses sanserif.

In version three (the current release), the font setting that is affected is `unit-font-command`, so you want

```latex
\AtBeginDocument{\sisetup{unit-font-command = \mathrm}}
```

In version two, you will need to change a slightly different setting:

```latex
\AtBeginDocument{\sisetup{math-rm=\mathrm, text-rm=\rmfamily}}
```

(The font setup is very different between the two versions, partly driven by the desire to better support things like `beamer`.)

Answer (score 3):

In a recent version, `siunitx` has also added the `mode`, `reset-text-family`, `reset-text-series`, and `reset-text-shape` options.  With these, on can tell `siunitx` to respect the `beamer` settings.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{structurebold}  % Only to show series changes
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame \SI{1}{\metre}}
\end{frame}

\sisetup{mode=match,
         reset-text-family=false,
         reset-text-series=false,
         reset-text-shape=false}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame \SI{2}{\metre}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Other font settings are detailed in section 4.2 of the manual.

Answer (score 2):

In the **preamble** of the document add this two lines:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all = true, detect-family = true}
```

Afterwards, in the **document body**, `siunitx` will follow your global settings, but if you change the font in a block, then `siunitx` will follow those changes too. For example:

```
\SI{0.8393}{\metre} %global settings
\begingroup
\sffamily

\SI{0.8393}{\metre}
\endgroup
```

Also check you are using the `siunitx` commands. As you typed `\SI{1}{m}`, but instead, it should be written as `\SI{1}{\metre}`