# Can siunitx use roman when familydefault is set to sans serif?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, siunitx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I make siunitx commands use serif fonts like the rest of the math in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66713/can-i-make-siunitx-commands-use-serif-fonts-like-the-rest-of-the-math-in-beamer)

I have a MWE showing setting the family default to sans serif with `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`. When this is done, no matter what settings to siunitx I have tried to use (shown in the example), I can't get the math modes (`$$` and `\[\]`) to display units and numbers in the roman serif font.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-mode=false,detect-family=false,
        detect-display-math=false,detect-shape=false,
        mode=math}

\begin{document}
text where you have \SI{450}{\volt}\\
$\textrm{inline math} \quad \sin^2(x) \quad \SI{450}{\volt}\\
\textrm{textrm V}$
\[\textrm{math environment}\quad \SI{450}{\volt}\]
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Ideally, I would expect the units given in text to be typeset in sans serif (even though this is considered naughty by SI standards), and the units inside `$$` or `\[\]` to be typeset in roman or whatever the current math font is.

I have noticed that it can get halfway there if you use `\sfseries` instead of `\familydefault`, meaning that text and `$$` will be typeset sans serif, while `\[\]` can be typeset roman. That solution is a problem for my documents, since I use sans serif for section headings as well.

Answer (score 2):

Joseph pointed me in the right direction with this question [Can I make siunitx commands use serif fonts like the rest of the math in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66713/can-i-make-siunitx-commands-use-serif-fonts-like-the-rest-of-the-math-in-beamer). Beyond adding the `\AtBeginDocument` as recommended there, I changed `text-rm=\rmfamily` to `text-rm=\sffamily` to get sans serif mid text, then removed the `mode` setting and changed `detect-mode=true`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-mode=true,detect-family=false,
        detect-display-math=false,detect-shape=false}
\AtBeginDocument{\sisetup{math-rm=\mathrm, text-rm=\sffamily}}


\begin{document}
text where you have \SI{450}{\volt}\\
$\textrm{inline math} \quad \sin^2(x) \quad \SI{450}{\volt}\\
\textrm{textrm V}$
\[\textrm{math environment}\quad \SI{450}{\volt}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE showing sans in text, roman in all math]